# How can I parse a CSV into array with first value as key?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, key

So I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
12345, Here is some text
20394, Here is some more text
```

How can I insert this into an array that looks like so

```
$text = "12345" => "Here is some text",
        "20394" => "Here is some more text";
```

This is what I currently had to get a single numerical based value on a one tier CSV

```
      if ($handle = fopen("$qid", "r")) {

          $csvData = file_get_contents($qid);
          $csvDelim = "\r";

          $qid = array();
          $qid = str_getcsv($csvData, $csvDelim);

      } else {

          die("Could not open CSV file.");

      }
```

Thanks for the replies, but I still see a potential issue.  With these solutions, wouldn't the values store in this way:

```
$array[0] = 12345
$array[1] = Here is some text 20394
$array[2] = Here is some more text
```

If I tried this on the example csv above, how would the array be structured?

Comment: Do comma's occur within the text?

Comment: Your delimiter should be `','`, not `"\r"`

Comment: What you ask...it cannot be done, computers are not capable of such black magic. You'd need to write several thousand lines of code in assembler and have at least 16 cores in your computer to even attempt it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `fgetcsv()` to read a line from a file into an array. So something like this:

```
$a = array();
$f = fopen(....);
while ($line = fgetcsv($f))
{
    $key = array_shift($line);
    $a[$key] = $line;
}
fclose($f);
var_dump($a);
```

Comment: replace `fopen` with `fgetcsv`

Comment: @Sarfaz: erm, `fgetcsv` still requires a handle from `fopen`? Or did there used to be a `fread` that needed to be replaced?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the first row in the CSV file contains the column headers, this will create an associative array using those headers for each row's data:

```
$filepath = "./test.csv";
$file = fopen($filepath, "r") or die("Error opening file");
$i = 0;

while(($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    if($i == 0) {
        $c = 0;
        foreach($line as $col) {
            $cols[$c] = $col;
            $c++;
        }
    } else if($i > 0) {
        $c = 0;
        foreach($line as $col) {
            $data[$i][$cols[$c]] = $col;
            $c++;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading a file I can recommend using something like fgetcsv()
This will read each line in the CSV into an array containing all the columns as values.

https://www.php.net/fgetcsv

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv_lines = explode('\n',$csv_text);
foreach($csv_lines as $line) {
  $csv_array[] = explode(',',$line,1);
}
```

edit - based on code posted after original question:

```
  if ($handle = fopen("$qid", "r")) {

      $csvData = file_get_contents($qid);
      $csvDelim = "\r"; // assume this is the line delim?

      $csv_lines = explode($csvDelim,$csvData);
      foreach($csv_lines as $line) {
        $qid[] = explode(',',$line,1);
      }

  } else {

      die("Could not open CSV file.");

  }
```

Comment: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in C:\xampp\htdocs\hint_updater\index.php on line 39

Comment: Oops, haha, well, $qid is used for both the string and the array, I did not notice that.  Try redeclaring $qid as an array before the "foreach" loop as you did in your code

$csv_lines = explode($csvDelim,$csvData);
$qid = array();
      foreach($csv_lines as $line) {
        $qid[] = explode(',',$line,1);
      }

Might be good to do $qid_array instead as well so you don't lose the original file string.

Answer (score 0):

With your new file with two columns, $qid should become an array with two values for each line.

```
$csvDelim = ",";
$qid = str_getcsv($csvData, $csvDelim);
$text[$qid[0]] = $qid[1];
```